# HTML5 Endless Background Animation

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a background image for animation.

How can i do endless animation ?

(If animation goes right side of page , i want to see it in appear in left side of page)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The original code from [David Walsh - CSS Background Animations](https://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css)

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
#animate-area {
  width: 560px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(https://davidwalsh.name/demo/bg-clouds.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I posted this because you said left to right. 
You can use something like this.

```css
#horizontal-scroll {
  width: 1439px;
  height: 1170px;
  background: black url(https://assets.periscope.tv/images/map.svg);
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 50s linear infinite;
  animation: backgroundScroll 50s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
background-position: -1439px 0;
  }
  to {
background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
background-position: -1439px 0;
  }
  to {
background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal-scroll"></div>
```

Comment: thanks , works but how can i make that like : https://www.periscope.tv/404 (.e : background image ) animation restarts in your answer

Comment: If you like I can make it identical with the colors. I did not know if you wanted to see how it works or a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes customname 
{
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to   { background-position: 100% 0; }
}


classname
{   
    background-image: url(Url of tyour file);
    width: width of the file; 
    height: Height of the file; 
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;  //Repeating through X axis only 

    animation: customname 40s linear infinite; 
}
```